# Sending email with attachment using Rails 4 and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 application with carrierwave handling file uploads. It's mounted correctly and the files are stored properly. However, I am unable to send those as attachments using Activemailer. Here's the mailer that I'm using:

```
def trigger_email(send_mail, contact, user)
    @mailer = send_mail
    @email = contact.email
    @user = User.find(user)
    attachments[@mailer.attachment.original_filename] = File.read(@mailer.attachment.current_path)
    mail(to: @email, subject: @mailer.subject, from: @user.email)
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: how are you storing the attachments? are they in the file system?

Comment: @jvnill yes, the files are stored in the filesystem at public/uploads/...

Comment: you're not getting any errors? or are you not getting any emails?

Comment: @jvnill I dont see any errors. The mails are sent out fine without any attachments.

Comment: no clue. try setting on `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors` to true if you haven't done that already

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution that works for me (rails 4.2, ruby 2.2.0, development env, local storage)

```
  def send_email email, whatever
    attachments[whatever.attachment.file.filename.to_s] = whatever.attachment.read
    mail(to: email, subject: whatever.subject)
  end
```

**remember** to add both the email types (.text.erb and .html.erb)

hope that will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

something like this in my `Mailer` worked like a charm

```
  all_documents.each do |document|
    filename = document.pdf_file.file.filename
    attachments[filename] = document.pdf_file.read
    puts "attached!"
  end
```

look for `file.filename` as well as `read` attributes in `your carrierwave uploader model` in my case my uploader's column name is `pdf_file`